# Why is an empty value in a shorthand if-then-else returning `true`?

Tags: php, if-statement, control-structure, shorthand-if

This is not exactly a "problem", but more a "why" question.

Based on the following example:

```
echo 'test' . ( true ?  : 'some-test' );
```

Why is the result of this: `test1` instead of what one might expect: `test`.

Or in other words: Why is an empty return statement `1` (or actually `true`) instead of `null` ?

Comment: It is echoing test1 because true is always 1 when you echo it. Try replacing true with false. And guess what happens?

Comment: try echo 'test' . ( true ? ''  : 'some-test' ); cause true always return 1

Comment: That I do understand. The real question is: why is an empty value returned as true in the first place. I would expect this if i did `(true ? true : 'some-test')`

Comment: @RakeshSharma I know how to avoid this. As stated it is not a "problem" . I am just very curious why a true is returned in the first place, instead of a null.

Comment: ohh got your question

Comment: Edited the question to make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[As of PHP 5.3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), the middle part of the ternary `?:` operator can be omitted.
`foo ?: bar` is equivalent to `foo ? foo : bar`. So `true ?: ...` always returns the first `true`.

`foo ? : bar` with the meaning of "nothing if true" is and was always invalid, since this expression *has* to return *something*, it can't just return nothing. If anything, you'd want this: `foo ? null : bar`.

Comment: Interesting, so `?` and `:` are still treated as two separate tokens and the parser just checks if there is an expression at all between them regardless of whitespace? I guess that's how it retains the title "ternary operator" while appearing to accept two expressions at the very least.

Comment: Apparently. I wasn't aware of that, but it makes sense to treat it that way instead of creating a new operator `?:`.

Comment: Interesting how you use stuff for a long time, only to discover much later -WHY- it actually does what it does :) Never knew it returned the operator by default if the first statement is empty. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

It is because of PHP 5.3

"Since PHP 5.3 it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression `expr1 ?: expr3` returns `expr1` if `expr1` evaluates to `TRUE`, and `expr3` otherwise."

[Ternary Operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Answer (score 1):

### The Elvis operator

There's some extra whitespace, but that syntax is commonly known as [the elvis operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator).

Consider the following:

```
$result = ($this ?: $that);
```

`$result` will be `$this` if `$this` is truthy, otherwise it will be `$that`.

Therefore when doing the equivalent of:

```
echo (true ?: 'some-test');
```

The result is *always*:

```
echo true;
```

Or the string "1".

### Whitespace is not equivalent to null

Note that this:

```
$var = (true ?      : 'some-test');
```

is *not* equivalent to:

```
$var = (true ? null : 'some-test');
```

Only in the latter example will `$var` be null as it's a standard ternary if statement; the first statement is a huge-quiffed elvis operator.

Comment: i like that ... Elvis operator

Comment: Your Elvis operator has turned into a tongue-sticking-out-with-a-freckle operator...!?

Comment: Extra whitespace was added for clarification. I indeed usually use it without them. But basically: when the statement is empty, the operator result is returned?

Comment: Indeed it does ( thx @lagbox for providing the link ). I did not know that the operator result is returned by default. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump(true ?  : 'some-test');` is `bool(true)`

`var_dump('test' . true);` is `string(5) "test1"`

This part is clear I hope.
What's strage here is that `true ? : 'some-test'` evaluates to `true`. This is a new behavior introduced in PHP 5.3 where if you omit the middle expression the value of the first one (`true` in your case) is returned.